# how can i select multiple cases in reading a large data file?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

```
SetDirectory["c:\\cygwin64\\homr\\Precision_3620"];
data=Drop[Import["output2001111.f15","Table"],17];
list=Cases[data,{_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _} | {_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _}]
```

[![i have described in this picture what i want to do][3]][3]

you can download data file in this link http://www.filedropper.com/output2001111
[image: what i want to extract is described in this image]

if i use the following code still it does not give me required result.

```
bb=Cases[list,{1,2,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}|{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,x_/;x>=27&&x<=39,_,_,_,_,_,_}|{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}|{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}]
```

this does not gives me batch that is red box in image.

Comment: What does "sets of lines like this" mean? Clearly describe the criteria for keeping a batch of lines and what a batch of lines is.

Comment: by set of lines i mean the highlighted red box has 4 Rows

Comment: @IrfanS you are missing a comma in your code above I can see a _ _

Comment: @AliHashmi oh yes edited , comma , its typo mistake while typing here.

Comment: @Edmund by set of lines i mean batch of lines(4 rows) enclosed in red box in picture

Answer (score 1):

if the input is consistently in groups of four rows like that you can do something like:

```
Select[Partition[data,4] , #[[1,1]]==1&&#[[1,2]]==2&&27<=#[[2,11]]<=39 & ]
```

The pattern approach should be something like this:

```
SequenceCases[
 data , {{1, 2, ___}, {_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, 
   n_ /; 27 <= n <= 39, ___}, {___}, {___}}]
```

(I did not download your data to test )

Comment: Thanks George second code line worked close to the required answer but now it is taking the whole batch of 4 lines as one element.

Comment: thanks for helping me. this works i further extracted data. thanks